# Toggle multiple items but wishing to only have one visible at a time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle, css-selectors

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMLwc/5/)

This is what I would like it to do:

1. Each red box ( `<span class="more">` ) to show/hide the description (`<div class="description">` )
2. The "close" link to also hide the description
3. If there is already a description open, this needs to close when another opens. So there is only ever one visible at a time.

Points 1 & 2, so far so good. But I'm stuck on point 3 - I've tried to find the other descriptions to hide them, but this fails!

```
$(".description").not(this).next(".description").removeClass("show")
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thanks so much for the speedy response! :)
I've applied your suggestion here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvusg/1/
It fixes point 3, but breaks point 1 unfortunately. x x

Comment: if you comment on his answer he will get a notification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take care of it: http://jsfiddle.net/SMLwc/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".more").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).next(".description").toggleClass("show")
      .parent().siblings().find(".description").removeClass("show");
  });

  $(".close").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).parent(".description").toggleClass("show");
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's done it! When you use .toggleClass, do you have to have everything in the one line? I would love to know why mine and the other suggestions broken the toggle, but yours didn't. Thanks again x x

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but it makes sense to just chain rather than reselecting or storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 4 to this:

```
$(".description").removeClass("show"),
```

Since you're new one isn't showing yet, it doesn't matter that you're turning them all off.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dvusg/1/
Same problem as Gorden, I think it breaks point 1 - as the toggle no longer works x x

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".description").removeClass("show"),
$(this).next(".description").toggleClass("show");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SMLwc/6/)

Comment: Thanks again, but point one "Each red box ( <span class="more"> ) to show/hide the description (<div class="description"> )" now doesn't work. Am I missing something? x x